# How to input `---++` in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want input `++--` in cell excel but error

[image]

How to input the `++--` or `----` as shown above.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just precede it with a quote character:

```
'++--
```

This forces Excel to treat it a text rather than numeric entry, and it's the numeric entry that causes the problem since it expectes a digit somewhere in there.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to make excel treat your input as a text rather than a formula.

- Change the cells format to text before entering: `++--`
- Enter a character that identifies your input as a text: `'++--`
- Input a Formula that outputs a text to the cell: `="++--"`

all three approaches work equally well.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the cells you want the input to be placed
2. Right click-->Format cells
3. In the first tab (Number), select the Category to be Text

Answer (score 2):

Start the cell with a ' character.